# Can someone help me check my understanding of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in an intro linear algebra class and we're learning subspaces. This is one of my homework problems, and I just want to make sure I both solved it correctly and am understanding the solution I came up with.

Let $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\5\end{bmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-4\\-5\\8\end{bmatrix}, $ and $ w = \begin{bmatrix}8\\2\\-9\end{bmatrix}$. Determine if $w$ is in the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

**My answer:**

I created an aumented matrix with $v_1$, $v_2$ and $w$: $\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & 8\\3 & -5 & 2\\5 & 8 & -9\end{bmatrix}$.

I then row-reduced this matrix, until I ended up with: ~$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -16 \\ 0 & 1& -10\\ 0 & 0 & -18\end{bmatrix}$

Clearly, the augmented matrix has no solution, so $w$ is not the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

**My reasoning:**

In general, we know that in $\mathbb R^n$, $H = span\{u_1...u_p\}$ is a subsapce of $\mathbb R^n$, where $u_1...u_p$ are vectors. So in this case we are trying to find if $span\{v_1, v_2\}$  is $w$. Meaning there is some linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ that is equal to $w$. Since there is no solution to the augmented matrix, $w$ couldn't be in the subspace $H$ generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

I feel like this explanation makes sense, but I sometimes mess up my definitions, which is why I want to double check. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Do you mean "Determine if $w$ is $\textbf{in}$ the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$"?

Comment: The question you asked makes no sense. $w$ is a vector, not a subspace, so asking if "$w$ is the subspace generated by $v_1, v_2$" makes no sense. I believe you ask if $w$ belongs to the subspace generated by $v_1, v_2$. If so, you need to check if there is some linear combination (not every linear combination, this is impossible) of $v_1,v_2$ which is equal to $w$. In other words, you ask if there are some $\lambda, \mu\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda v_1+\mu v_2=w$. In order to check this, you indeed have to solve a system of linear equations.

Comment: Once the typo is corrected in the problem statement, the process you used is correct.

Comment: I just re-read the question. It does indeed say determine if w is "in" the subspace, rather than "is" the subspace. I definitely mis-read it and now see how my original solution doesn't make sense with that typo. Thanks everyone!